# Revert Bitnami Wordpress after running bnconfig & updateip

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

From the AWS Market Place I created a Wordpress Stack on Amazon EC2. After the installation, I ran the following commands:

1)  sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/bnconfig --appurl /

2)  sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/updateip --appurl /

I would like to back out the changes that were made from running these commands.  I'm not sure what to do to revert Wordpress to a state before these commands were executed.

I DID THE FOLLOWING:

1)  uncommented out the two alias's from  httpd-prefix.conf

Alias /wordpress/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/"

Alias /wordpress "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

2)  Changed httpd-app.conf to its previous state:

```
Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks

AllowOverride None

<IfVersion < 2.3 >
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
Require all granted
</IfVersion>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]

<IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteOptions Inherit
   RewriteRule ^(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://uds=%2fopt%2fbitnami%2fphp%2fvar%2frun%2fwordpress.sock/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [P,L]
</IfDefine>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the httpd_prefix.conf file found in /installdir/apps/your_application/conf/httpd-prefix.conf

add this to the file:

```
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
Alias /wordpress/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/"
```

Uncomment the alias line if it is commented

P.S.  As far as I know the installdir is /opt/bitnami/

Comment: SackBoy B, I updated the issue with what I've done thus far.  I already made the changes that you mentioned and there seems to be more that needs to be reverted in the configuration.  it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the manual approach to find what needed to be undone with the configuration:

http://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_Wordpress#Manual_approach

In the httpd-prefix.conf I had the following line:

DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

Once I commented out the above line.  Everything began to work correctly.